# Getting 'Uncaught TypeError: handleChange is not a function' while trying to read input from text field

Tags: reactjs, react-native, runtime-error

I am trying to call this handleTextChange function (in Form.js) from another component in a different file (Input.js), but it throws the error:

Uncaught TypeError: handleChange is not a function

I am new to learning ReactJS, and I'm following a tutorial, so do not know much about the language yet. This method was working for the course instructor, so I am not sure where I am going wrong with this.

Here is my function. I am calling it from inside the render method of my Class component Form

```
handleTextChange = name => event => {
        this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
        console.log('name', name)
    }

<Input 
   name='userName' 
   label='Username' 
    defaultValue={userName} 
    handleChange={this.handleTextChange} 
/>
```

```
const Input = ({ name, label, value, handleChange }) => (
    <Component>
        <Label htmlFor={name}>{label}</Label>
        <StylizedInput onChange={handleChange(name)} type='text' defaultValue={value}/>
    </Component>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to call handleChange in Your component like this if you want to pass some arguments

```
<StylizedInput onChange={() => handleChange(name)} type='text' defaultValue={value}/>
```

without function arguments you can call the function like this

```
 <StylizedInput onChange={handleChange} type='text' defaultValue={value}/>
```

Comment: Hi Rajneesh! Thanks for suggesting, however I have already tried this and it's still not working for me

Comment: can you verify that handleChange function is actually there in your input component.

Comment: The handleChange function is in a different component (Form), I am invoking <Input /> from inside <Form /> and trying to pass the function from Form to Input. Form and Input components are also located in different files.

Comment: yes that's not an issue, can you just console log handleChange and check if it is undefined or is a Function

Comment: I am console logging both the name component and the event inside handleTextChange, but neither is appearing on the console